# Pycharm Terminal opens Canopy

Tags: terminal, pycharm, canopy

I have installed both PyCharm and Canopy at my computer. When I try to run a .py file from the terminal of the PyCharm then it opens the file in the Canopy Editor. What I have tried is:

```
Settings->Console->Python Console-> Change the intepreter
```

but didn't work. Does anyone has a clue how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to associate Python files with PyCharm.

Comment: @JonathanMarch I was hoping to do that by changing the interpreter. Is there any other way?

Comment: Did you try "python myfile.py"?